# Cannot GET the JSON files

Tags: javascript, php, json, .htaccess

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "check",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^1.0.5",
    "react-image": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "selectn": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.config,js file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.mp3$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: "./api",
        to: "./api",
        force: true
      },
      {
        from: "./catalogue.pdf",
        to: "./catalogue.pdf",
        force: true
      },
      {
        from: "./src/smartmenus-1.1.0",
        to: "./smartmenus-1.1.0/",
        force: true
      },
      {
        from: "./src/resources",
        to: "./resources/",
        force: true
      },
      {
        from: "./src/favicon.ico",
        to: "./favicon.ico",
        force: true
      }
    ])
  ],
  devtool: "source-map"
};
```

settings.php file:

```
?php

define('FILE_PATH', '../files/');
define('JSON_PATH', FILE_PATH . 'json/');


?>
```

get.php file:

```
<?php

require_once('settings.php');

$file = preg_replace('/(\.){2,}/', '', $_GET['file']);
```

$fullPath = FILE_PATH . $file;

```
$mimetype = mime_content_type('../files/'.$file);

if('application/octet-stream' == $mimetype && 'mp3' == end(explode(".", '../files/'.$file))) {
    $mimetype = 'audio/mpeg';
}

header("X-Sendfile: $fullPath");
header("Content-type: $mimetype");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');

echo $fullPath;

die();
?>
```

.htaccess file:

```
<Files get.php>
    XSendFile On
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /api/

    #Note: If not(!) match on any of the three conditions below then
    # perform the RewriteRule
    # !=not, ^/beginning of string, $=end of string
    # [L] means do not continue processing this file any further

    #We do not want to redirect any files that are a direct link to an image or css file

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}&api=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

index.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('settings.php');

$url = trim($_GET['api'], '/');
$counter = 0;

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== 'q' && $key !== 'api') {
        if ($counter === 0) {
            $url .= '?';
        } else {
            $url .= '&';
        }

        $url .= $key . '=' . $value;
        $counter++;
    }
}

$splitUrl = explode('/', $url);
$firstSection = (count($splitUrl) > 0) ? $splitUrl[0] : null;

if (!empty($firstSection)
    && in_array($firstSection, [
        'main_menu',
        'birds',
        'birds1',
        'Waterfowl',
        'Land-Birds',
        'fish',
        'food',
        'food1',
        'animal_homes',
        'verbs',
        'wild_animals',
        'buildings',
        'bones',
        'male_kinship_terms',
        'kinship_terms',
        'female_kinship_terms',
        'sixSeasons',
        'trees',
        'yearly_calendar',
        'syllabic_matching_game1',
        'syllabic_matching_game2',
        'syllabic_matching_game3',
        'syllabic_matching_game4',
        'syllabic_matching_game5',
        'syllabic_matching_game6',
        'syllabic-chart',
        'syllabic_chart',
        'numbers',
        'northern_saskatchewan_place',
        'household_items',
        'classroom_objects',
        'catalog'
    ])
) {
    $file = "temp_debug.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $firstSection);

    echo file_get_contents(JSON_PATH . $url . '.json');
}
```

**GET http://localhost:8080/api/main_menu 404 (Not Found)**

main_menu.json is a json file. It is in the files folder on the root of the project.But everything is loading without the images and the json files! When i am going to the link http://localhost:8080/api/main_menu it shows Cannot GET /api/main_menu and it should be redirect to the http://localhost:8080/api/index.php?api=main_menu and fetch the file through htaccess. And on the other side for images and audio files, it is like http://localhost:8080/api/get.php?file=media/Home/bald_eagle.png and should fetch the files. But it only downloads the get.php file itself!

Comment: Where does `file` in `$_GET['file']` come from? Also, you define two constants `FILE_PATH` and `JSON_PATH` but don't seem to be using them. I would also recommend using `= __DIR__ . '/../files/` instead of just `= '../files/`. The magic constant `__DIR__` will return the absolute path of the file it's written in. Use that in your constant and use those constants in your application instead

Comment: I have tried this one. But it is not working. When i am going to "get.php?file=media/Home/animalhome.jpg" ,it is downloading the get.php file instead of the jpg file!

Comment: Have you double checked that `$_GET` contains what you expect? Also, please edit the question to be clear. Currently, you're showing us some example URL's while your code are using other variables (like the `$_GET['file']`. The examples should be consistent or we're just stumbling in the dark.

Comment: I have edited the ques. @MagnusEriksson